# wpf calendar control - subclass

Tags: wpf, calendar

I have the word "subclass" in the title because that's the only idea I have for doing this, but maybe not?

What I need is to only use the years of a calendar control - I don't need either the months view nor the days view. I thought of writing a custom control that does this, but since calendar already has the very cool "Decade" view, I wanted to use that.

I tried handling the DisplayDateChanged event and forcing the mode back to Decade, but what happens is that the months show on click, and then disapear showing the Decade view again.

Any "interesting hacks" for doing this?

In C++, I always knew I can do a "real subclass" and intervene in the control's behavior - Can this be done?